RDS MySQL not using NVMe instance storage - no benefit of "Optimised Reads"
I am load testing various RDS instances trying to optimise db price/performance
I had seen this doc https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/rds-optimized-reads.html and it sounded like a __d instance with local SSD storage would likely improve performance
The r6gd.2xlarge that I tested has 1x474GB NVMe, which is big enough to fit the whole dataset (EBS volume is only 400GB).
However when I check the metrics in Performance Insights the stats for ReadIOPSLocalStorage and ReadThroughputLocalStorage are basically zero. I do see a big chunk of WriteThroughputLocalStorage but it doesn't seem to be reading anything.
And if I test an r6g instance without the NVMe the performance is basically the same.
So it doesn't seem to be doing anything.
The AWS doc says it will automatically do "Optimised Reads" if you deploy one of the __d instances. But I am wondering if some manual config changes are needed to make best use of it?
There is this note in the doc:

Set the internal_tmp_mem_storage_engine parameter to TempTable, and set the temptable_max_mmap parameter to match the size of the available storage on the instance store.

Currently the latter value is 1073741824 i.e. 1 GiB, well short of the NVMe size
I tried bumping this up to 246960619520 but didn't see any more usage or very different performance, and FreeLocalStorage stat shows it's basically all free still.
How do I get benefit from local SSD storage and "Optimised Reads" on my RDS MySQL instance?
(It's recently deployed, on MySQL 8.0.35)

A high-performance storage technology only helps if your database workload is I/O-bound a lot of the time. If your queries are served from data that's already in RAM (e.g. the InnoDB buffer pool), then fancy local storage won't make any difference. RAM is still lower latency than any current storage technology.

I believe my workload is heavily IO bound, it's doing ~12000 Read IOPS from EBS and the cpu utilization metrics show most time spent in nice, followed by wait and then system... this is why I was hoping it would do something like  automatically move the indexes and/or big chunk of data to the SSD. But AFAICT from doc (which is quite opaque) it moves some kinds of temp files and they seem way under utilized for the amount of SSD that is available.

As far as I know, RDS does not allow you to move the data directory to a non-EBS volume. You could do that if you use EC2 and configure your own MySQL Server instance.

At the moment "RDS Optimized Reads" seems worthless, am trying to understand under what scenario it is useful, or if there are config tweaks I can make to take better use of it

(My workload is mostly read-only analytical queries)

I've done a lot of RDS benchmarking, and my conclusion is that it's pretty useless if you have need for high performance. Its chief benefit is that it's a managed database instance, so you don't have to do a lot of work for upgrades or backups or failover. But it's basically a toy platform, suitable only for light database traffic.

Use the slowlog to determine the "worst" queries.  It may be that adding a 'composite' index will help signiticantly.

maybe I'm posting on the wrong site ... I'm trying to understand why my db doesn't appear to be making use of the "Optimised Reads" feature that is supposed to be auto-enabled when using an r6gd instance type

This doc says:

The following use cases are candidates for RDS Optimized Reads:

...
Applications that run on-demand or dynamic reporting queries that involve complex operations, such as queries with GROUP BY and ORDER BY clauses


...which is why I thought it would be useful for my db workload.
However this doc better explains what "Optimised Reads" actually does:

The following temporary objects are stored in the instance store volumes for Optimized Reads: internal temporary files, internal on-disk temporary tables, user-created temp tables, memory map files created by the TempTable engine, and temporary binlog cache files. Offloading the temporary objects to the instance store volume benefits use cases such as queries that involve large temporary objects like temporary tables or sort files. Furthermore, it helps when application queries involve using temporary user-created tables, complex CTEs, derived tables, or sub-queries.

So it only benefits queries which use temporary tables that are too large to fit in memory:

A key simplification for manageability for the TempTable storage engine is that it uses a memory pool for all sessions that use it. The memory limit, set by temptable_max_ram, applies to the sum of memory consumption from concurrent sessions. This is different from the MEMORY storage engine, where the memory limit, set by the smaller tmp_table_size and max_heap_table_size, is per table, specific to a session. The TempTable storage engine also has its own disk overflow mechanism. You can configure it to overflow either to memory-mapped temporary files or to InnoDB on-disk internal temporary tables. A memory-mapped file provides the mapping between a file and memory space that speeds up file read and write operations. In addition to the memory limit, these two separate overflow paths can bring out distinctive aspects of internal temporary table storage engines and directly impact query performance.

So... I may have some queries which use temp tables, but maybe not many, or they mostly don't reach the threshold to spill over to the NVMe storage.
Interesting/frustratingly it looks like the same feature for Postgres probably works more like I was hoping for:
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/new-amazon-aurora-optimized-reads-for-aurora-postgresql-with-up-to-8x-query-latency-improvement-for-i-o-intensive-applications/

Tiered cache – This allows you to extend your DB instance caching capacity by utilizing the local NVMe storage. It automatically caches database pages about to be evicted from the in-memory database buffer pool, offering up to eight times better latency for queries that were previously fetching data from Aurora storage.

